# Cross Variation of stochatic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

Let $f \in L^2(\langle M\rangle)$ and $g \in L^2(\langle N \rangle)$, where $M$ and $N$ are two martingales. So we have the well defined stochastic integrals,defining the processes $I_M(f)_t = \int_0^t f(s)dM_s$ and $I_N(g)_t\int_0^tg(s)dN_s$. How can I show that

$$
  \langle I_M(f), I_N(g) \rangle_t = \int_0^tf(s)g(s) d\langle M, N \rangle_s
$$ 
?

Comment: Do you know that the results holds for $f=g$?

Comment: This is the direct result of a theorem. Are you asking that we prove the theorem (or reference the proof) or show how it applies in this case to give what you want?

Comment: @cgmil what is the theorm that you are referencing?